# Am I hurting my party by being a Bard?

Tags: dnd-5e, bard, party

I have a group of 3-5 people (2 of the people are often busy and show up about half the time), and I am a Bard. I was wondering if it is worth it to be bard in such a small group. I am the only spellcaster, so am I hurting the party by being a support class? The campaign we are running is about 80% combat, so I want to know if I would be a detriment if didn't play cleric or wizard.

My group is comprised of a Monk, Rogue, Rogue(Uses powerful crossbow instead of melee), Barbarian and me, a multiclassed Bard 4/Warlock 1 (Yes, I get it's a bad combo but I get 9 proficiencies and detect magic at will.)

The campaign we are running is a dungeon crawler that is heavily story based. It's kind of an average campaign with a few traps, locks, RP events and puzzles thrown in the mix. I don't really know how else to describe it.

I am afraid that by being a Bard I would be not as useful as a main healer like a cleric.

Comment: Why you think you might be harming your party (what evidence do you have of negative effects)?

Comment: Bard/Warlock is a _great_ combo, Bards badly need a good cantrip, and Warlocks have the greatest of them all. Just take another level of Warlock, to add your Charisma to the Eldritch Blast

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is ***NEVER*** hurting the party to be a bard!  A group of 4 is actually the average every table and chart is compared to.  Above 4 and you're getting into EZ-Mode , and below 4 and things start to be a bit more difficult.  So a group of 4 PLUS a Bard is pretty nifty.  If the other classes are well rounded, then you shouldn't have many problems.  Bards are perfect multi taskers.  Observe:

As a bard you know a total of 22 spells at level 20, AND you have enough spell slots to match.  Most get more spells than they have slots for.  Your cantrip choices are amazing.  Not to mention if you specialize in a certain Bardic class, you can then start taking spells from OTHER classes.  You get both healing, defensive, and offensive spells on a whim.

**Bardic Inspiration** is no joke, and extremely helpful in almost every situation.

**Jack of All Trades** is where you begin turning into a multi tasker.

**Song of Rest** is where it get's considerably helpful

> **Song of rest** PHB pg 54 *"...If you and any friendly creatures who can hear you regain hitpoints at the end of a short rest (As when expending hit die to regain HP) each of those creatures regain an extra 1d6 HP..."*

And those extra HP get better as you level, just with your Inspiration die.

Expertise (Which you can apply to up to four abilities) furthers your skill applications.

The Bardic Colleges are masterful at one thing or another and I wont list all the skills here as you have no doubt dove into the players handbook and seen for yourself.
All I'm really trying to say?  Your teammates will thank you for being there when they need it....especially for that healing magic.

Comment: My group of 6 has one bard, a bard/paladin, an eldritch knight fighter, arcane trickster rogue and a ranger and hasn't been hurting for any of the impact that a wizard or cleric brings to the table. Personally, if I was going to put all my magic eggs in one basket, it'd be a warlock I'd be more worried about than a bard.

Comment: @polisurgist yeah, but no one in my party took proficiency in anything but perception, deception, athletics, sneak or persuasion. And that's scattered among them. With 2 levels in warlock I will have 9 proficiencies that can help the party.

Comment: @Polisurgist Hey, hey hey.  Do **not** knock the Warlock brah!  I'm a Paladin all the way, but the Warlock in our party is pretty impressive around level 4 / 5.  That Eldritch Blast tho....  Still, Warlock has nothing on Sorcerer with those Sorcery Points and Meta magic.  Sorcerer is like whoa.

Comment: Oh, the warlock is great, but doesn't have the same flexibility other casters has, so I'd be cautious about them being the only caster in the group. It's a lot harder for them to be the Swiss Army knife.

Comment: A warlock has a ton a versatility when you look at his available options, but his choice is limited so that he has to specialize. Warlocks have their options available the most consistently compared to other casters, which they exchange their versatility for.

Answer (score 0):

Bards have two things going for them.

1) They have abilities that benefit that effects all allies.
2) They are able to fill in for (almost) any role.

Ability 1's power is proportional to number of players.

Ability 2's power is proportional to the number of roles not filled within the party.

So the bard is amazing in a group of 10 fighters and the bard, because both abilities 1 and 2 are good.
They are ok in a group of 10 characters of a variety of classes, as ability 1 is good.
They are ok by themselves, as ability 2 is good.
They are not suited to a group that contains 3-5 players and has a wide variety of classes represented.

To address your specific scenario, as you are in a normal sized group with most roles covered, I would suggest you would have a more powerful group if you were to take either a cleric or a wizard, instead of a bard.

However, that is not to say that you have to do it. It depends on how you enjoy playing the game. You shouldn't get locked into a class you don't enjoy just because 'the party needs it'. The DM will adjust difficulty to the party, so people can play the class they enjoy.

Comment: If he’s the only spellcaster, I doubt they have all roles covered.